# Pressing a key, then releasing it

Tags: vb.net, keypress, simulate

This is not a question as such, more a solution. I have been trying to code a routine which will allow me to press a key on my Joystick (which sends a DX button) and simulates pressing and holding a key in the down position at the same time. Basically, it boiled down to three lines of code:

```
    10. Public Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

    20. If (condition=true) then
    30.     keybd_event(Keys.Scroll, 0, 0, 0)
    40. Else
    50.     keybd_event(Keys.Scroll, 0, 2, 0)
    60. EndIf
```

Line numbers added for clarity. As you can see, line 20 holds down the SCROLL LOCK key, line 30 releases it again. Although the code works perfectly for my needs (in a 1 hour 35 minute session I experienced no problems in Falcon BMS 4.33U2, IVC Client, and FRAPS), to get this to work, I had to disable the MDA using Debug>Exceptions>Managed Debugging Assistants>PInvokeStackImbalance (thrown).

My question is - is this a "safe" way to program, or in other words, have I cheated somewhere to get this to work? If it is not "safe", is there a proper way to do the same thing?

Comment: `keybd_event` is deprecated, and so is `Declare...Lib`. The current way to send keyboard/mouse events is by using [**`SendInput()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx). See my keyboard input wrapper [**in this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809095/why-do-some-applications-not-accept-some-sendkeys-at-some-times/39811061#39811061).

Comment: Have a look at this example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx
It is for numloc, but according to the info you should  use KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY.

Second: what stands behind the COndition? Is it something like:
GetKeyboardState((LPBYTE)&keyState); E.g. to get the current key state?

Third you can try to use SetInput instead of keybg_event, since keybg_event is superseded

Comment: If the function was declared correctly, there should be no errors at all. The `Thrown` check box shouldn't be ticked for any exception by default, since it will break the application even if the exception is handled.

Comment: That is a VB6 declaration.  Long is not correct and trips the MDA.  Very nasty, never ignore that.  [Correct one is here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/keybd_event.html).

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment [**`keybd_event()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) is deprecated and replaced by [**`SendInput()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx). However the reason you are receiving a `PInvokeStackImbalance` exception is because the last two parameters is wrong in your function declaration.

Almost all `Declare...Lib` examples out there are designed for VB 6 or lower, where for example `Long` isn't the same as VB.NET's `Long` data type. I advice you to **always** look for P/Invoke snippets using the [**`DllImport` attribute**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). If you can't find a VB.NET version, you can look for C# snippets instead and convert them using an online converter.

To fix the error the last two parameters should be of type [**`UInteger`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x79h55x9.aspx) and [**`UIntPtr`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uintptr(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Public Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, ByVal dwExtraInfo As UIntPtr)
```

However, as I said it is recommended to stick to `DllImport`:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Shared Sub keybd_event(bVk As Byte, bScan As Byte, dwFlags As UInteger, dwExtraInfo As UIntPtr)
End Function
```

You can check [**pinvoke.net**](http://pinvoke.net) for P/Invoke snippets.

---

To use the today recommended method `SendInput()`, you can utilize my `InputHelper` class:

> **EDIT (2019-09-20)**
>
> `InputHelper` has since long been moved to its own library. The answer has been updated to reflect this change.
>
> **Download InputHelper from GitHub:**
>   https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/releases

For example:

```
If condition = True Then
    InputHelper.SetKeyState(Keys.Scroll, True) 'Key down.
Else
    InputHelper.SetKeyState(Keys.Scroll, False) 'Key up.
End If
```